# Once mail hosting through Gmail is setup, is it easy to change web hosts?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, g-suite, gmail, shared-hosting

I have a personal domain name, pointing to a simple cPanel-type shared hosting account.  About six months ago, I decided that I wanted to use Google Gmail for hosting my domain name's email.

In my shared hosting account, I added MX records pointing at Google.  I then went into my Google Apps admin console and told them I wanted use Gmail for my domain.  Google had me temporarily upload a small file to my webserver, to prove that I really controlled it, and then I was all setup.

Now, I want to change web hosting providers while keeping my email on Google.  I have established a new hosting account, and already setup the MX records properly.  However, I have not yet changed my domain's nameserver info to point at the new hosting account.

Before I make this switch, I am wondering whether the process will be seamless as far as Gmail goes?  Should I have to upload another verification file to my new webserver, or even tell Google anything about what I'm doing at all?  Or should the MX records on both web hosts mean that my email will flow smoothly to Google even as the namesever changes propagate throughout the Internet?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to make sure that your *new* nameserver has the exact same MX records as the old nameserver *before you do the switch*. Just as long as both of them are idential, you won't have any issues, because regardless of which nameserver is queried, they will both offer up the same MX records.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to worry about it. Once you confirm the ownership of a domain, it is done and no need to confirm it later in any case just keep your MX records identical.

More info on this is available [**here**](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171715)