# MX and NS entries

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I was wondering about my domain and if this is correct.

First of all this is my set up:

1. Domain registration at goddady.com
2. Hosting at dreamhost
3. mail at google apps

Until now I have set up the Google Apps MX entries in my domain through the GoDaddy manager, but now I want to set up the hosting I have from DreamHost.

I understand that all I have to do is to setup next dreamhost NS entries into the goddady domain manager:

```
NS1.DREAMHOST.COM.            66.33.206.206
NS2.DREAMHOST.COM.            208.96.10.221
NS3.DREAMHOST.COM.            66.33.216.216
```

My question is: will my mail keep working correctly once the MX entries I set up in GoDaddy are the google apps ones?

Comment: The confusion in the answers results from the ambiguous "hosting at dreamhost" in your question.  _What_, exactly, is to be hosted at Dreamhost?  Content HTTP service?  Content DNS service?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from the details you have provided that DreamHost are going to be your DNS provider.

So, once you have set up your MX records in DreamHost, you can switch your NameServers over at GoDaddy and everything will continue to work fine.

See also this almost (but not quite) identical question: [Once mail hosting through Gmail is setup, is it easy to change web hosts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/283255/once-mail-hosting-through-gmail-is-setup-is-it-easy-to-change-web-hosts/283258#283258)

Comment: But I don't understand why I should to setup the MX entries in dreamhost if the dns management is in goddady, is not ok with maintaining the mx entries in godaddy? what should I do then to keep 100% the DNS configuration into the goddady and have the mail in google apps and the hosting in dreamhost provider without using the dreamhost dns?

Comment: @unkown - If you update your nameservers in godaddy (which is what you've said you're going to do) to point to dreamhost, then *dreamhost* becomes your DNS provider. Otherwise, leave your DNS with godaddy, and *don't touch your NS records*

Comment: And how should I configure the goddady domain if I want to point to the dreamhost hosting without changing the ns entries?

Comment: @unkown - you have to point your NS records for the domain to the person who is hosting your DNS. So if you don't want to point them to dreamhost, then you'll need to point them to whoever is going to host your DNS.

Comment: What I definitively need according with my idea (having hosting and DNS management completely separated speaking about any kind of entries) is to let the MX entries as are in my domain manager and setup an A entry for the hosting.

Comment: @arrrrgv that's exactly what I'm looking for as well. Did you find a way to reset the NS servers to default so that the A records take effect?

Answer (score 0):

You will change the DNS records in the Domain control Panel At Godaddy and have to update the MX records at DreamHost for using Google Apps.

It is recommended to update the MX records in your hosting control panel prior to changing the DNS records at Domain Control panel for uninterrupted mail services.